# How do I fix the blank white screen after rendering a react app

Tags: reactjs

There is a blank screen when i launched the react app. I have tracked the error to the header container because the app renders just fine when I remove the container. Please help.

There are many questions on here but none of them are related to my problem.

Here is the error on Firefox devtools:
Uncaught TypeError: []["Scroll for more information"] is undefined
Header Header.jsx:11
React 8
workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
Header.jsx:11

I do not know what I did wrong.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppWrap } from '../../wrapper';

import './Header.scss';

const Header = () => {

  const [texts, setTexts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutIds = []

    [ "Hello  and welcome", 
      "I am Akim", 
      "A Freelance Web Developer", 
      "Let's work together and create something beautiful", 
      "Scroll for more information"].forEach((text, i) => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
          setTexts((prev) => [...prev, text])
        }, 1000 * i)

        timeoutIds.push(timeoutId)
    })

    return () => {
      timeoutIds.forEach((id) => clearTimeout(id))
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="app__header app__flex">
        <div className="app__header-badge">
          <div className="tag-cmp app__flex">
            {texts.map((text) => {
              return (
                <p key={text} className="p-text">{text}</p>
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AppWrap(Header, 'home');
```

Comment: Header Component has no problem : https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-architecture-ojgid5?file=/src/App.js:492-1009

Comment: but why is it showing the blank white screen?

Comment: what is wrapper and homein your code?

Comment: wrapper wraps every container to show navigation dots on the side while home is the id. Here is website the link: akim-portfolio.netlify.app

Comment: here is the error message from Firefox devtools:                                                                        Uncaught TypeError: []["Scroll for more information"] is undefined
    Header Header.jsx:11
    React 8
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
Header.jsx:11